# Is there a Free, professional, and lite video editor?

Tags: video-editing

I have a very weak graphics chip. Intel 384MB built-in. I can't afford to buy a new graphics card. It's been a two week since I started searching for a free video editor (similar to sony vegas).

I downloaded many versions of Openshot, blender VSE, Shortcut but some of them fail to open or the other open but are very laggy (very slow interface).

I also downloaded DaVinci Resolve, ivsEditFree, Kdenlive, light works, and many other programs. Some of them didn't work as well and some of them had no timeline (very simple / unprofessional).

I found out that most of the open source software is so heavy because they use the graphics card to run the interface.

Is there a **free** video editor that doesn't need a high-end graphics card? I need a one with timeline because What I'm going to do is to synchronize images with the narrator's voice (e.g. when he says: "A", the image that contains the letter "A" should appear). I'll also upload and monetize the video on YouTube.

System specs:

- CPU: Core 2 Duo 2.33GHz
- RAM: 3 GB

Comment: lightworks may work for you